# Auto scrolling in multiple tables of fixed heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can add auto scroll to single table of fixed height:

```
function scrollDiv_init() {
    DivElmnt = document.getElementById('tableDiv');
    ReachedMaxScroll = false;

    DivElmnt.scrollTop = 0;
    PreviousScrollTop  = 0;

    ScrollInterval = setInterval('scrollDiv()', ScrollRate);
}

function scrollDiv() {

    if (!ReachedMaxScroll) {
        DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
        PreviousScrollTop++;

        ReachedMaxScroll = DivElmnt.scrollTop >= (DivElmnt.scrollHeight - DivElmnt.offsetHeight);
    }
    else {
        ReachedMaxScroll = (DivElmnt.scrollTop == 0)?false:true;

        DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
        PreviousScrollTop--;
    }
}
```

However, I've multiple tables on a screen, generated at run time. Some of them requires auto scrolling if table body exceeds a fixed size. 
I can achieve the auto scroll in one table by referencing the table by it's id, but I'm not sure how to achieve this in case of multiple tables.

https://codepen.io/shubh2gupta/pen/WzdXpj this has few tables with fixed heights. Table 1 has auto scroll enabled but I'm not sure how to make it work for other tables as well. I want them to auto scroll whenever data is overflowed.

```js
function scrollDiv_init() {
    DivElmnt = document.getElementById('tableDiv');
    ReachedMaxScroll = false;

    DivElmnt.scrollTop = 0;
    PreviousScrollTop  = 0;
    ScrollRate =100;
    ScrollInterval = setInterval('scrollDiv()', ScrollRate);
}

function scrollDiv() {

    if (!ReachedMaxScroll) {
        DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
        PreviousScrollTop++;

        ReachedMaxScroll = DivElmnt.scrollTop >= (DivElmnt.scrollHeight - DivElmnt.offsetHeight);
    }
    else {
        ReachedMaxScroll = (DivElmnt.scrollTop == 0)?false:true;

        DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
        PreviousScrollTop--;
    }
}
```

```css
.scrollable{
 height:150px;
  width:200px;
 overflow-y:auto;
}

.inlineT{
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body onload="scrollDiv_init()">
<div id="bodyDiv">

  <div id = "tableDiv" class="scrollable inlineT">
      <strong>Table1</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div id = "tableDiv" class="scrollable inlineT">
      <strong>Table2</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div id = "tableDiv" class="scrollable inlineT">
    <strong>Table3</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div id = "tableDiv" class="scrollable inlineT">
    <strong>Table4</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div id = "tableDiv" class="scrollable inlineT">
    <strong>Table5</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div id = "tableDiv" class="scrollable inlineT">
    <strong>Table6</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>

  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div id = "tableDiv" class="scrollable inlineT">
    <strong>Table7</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div id = "tableDiv" class="scrollable inlineT">
    <strong>Table8</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>

  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can't you give them the same class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've put pretty much the code you had inside an object named `scrolly`. Then create an instance for every element containing the class `'.tableDiv'` and call the `scrolly` function `scrollInterval()`

Hope it helps.

```js
var scrolly = function(element){
    this.element = element
    this.reachedMaxScroll = false;
    this.scrollTop = 0;
    this.previousScrollTop  = 0;
    this.scrollRate =100;
    
    this.scrollInterval = function(){
        setInterval(
            (function(){
                this.scrollDiv()
            }).bind(this),
            this.scrollRate
        )
    };
    
    this.scrollDiv = function(){
        if (!this.reachedMaxScroll) {
            this.element.scrollTop = this.previousScrollTop;
            this.previousScrollTop++;

            this.reachedMaxScroll = this.element.scrollTop >= (this.element.scrollHeight - this.element.offsetHeight);
        } else {
            this.reachedMaxScroll = (this.element.scrollTop == 0)?false:true;

            this.element.scrollTop = this.previousScrollTop;
            this.previousScrollTop--;
        }
    };
};

var divElements = document.querySelectorAll('.tableDiv');
divElements.forEach(function(element){
    new scrolly(element).scrollInterval();
});
```

```css
.scrollable{
 height:150px;
  width:200px;
 overflow-y:auto;
}

.inlineT{
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="bodyDiv">

  <div class="tableDiv scrollable inlineT">
      <strong>Table1</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div class="tableDiv scrollable inlineT">
      <strong>Table2</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div class="tableDiv scrollable inlineT">
    <strong>Table3</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div class="tableDiv scrollable inlineT">
    <strong>Table4</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div class="tableDiv scrollable inlineT">
    <strong>Table5</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div class="tableDiv scrollable inlineT">
    <strong>Table6</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>

  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div class="tableDiv scrollable inlineT">
    <strong>Table7</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


  <div class="tableDiv scrollable inlineT">
    <strong>Table8</strong>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>
  <tr><td >NAME </td><td>TYPE </td><td>QUANT</td></tr>

  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: what to do if i wan't to stop this autoscroll on mouseover and      start it again on mouseout? I tried doing it but couldn't achieve it.

Comment: @shubhamgupta it's a good question! There are multiple ways to achieve it but basically you need to implement a "pauseScroll" function. Ask it as a new question and show what you have tried. If you want you can post the link of the new question here, if I have time I might have a look at it.